# Limit Calculation involving limit and failed root test

Tags: limits

How would you calculate the following:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}}{e^n}
$$

The root test of course doesn't help because it gives 1.

Answer (score 2):

Taking logarithm, we get

$$n^2\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})-n$$

$$=n^2\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}(1+\epsilon(n)\right)-n$$

$$\frac{-1}{2}(1+\epsilon(n))$$

thus the limit is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}.$$

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it's possible to do it without any differential theorem? Just with mere tricks of sequences?